# Different mode for extension based on file path

Tags: emacs, elisp

Basically, I've been trying nXhtml mode, and it's terribly slow and buggy in Emacs 24.

I'm working with PHP files. I'd like to load most files with `*.php` as `php-mode`, but if a file I'm visiting is in a `'/templates'` or `'/views'` folder, load the file in `html-mode`.

Renaming the files or changing the project structure are not options. I am using 24.1.1. I'm sure this is possible, so a decent pseudo-code solution that points in the right direction will be accepted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you want you need to put the correct regular expression in `auto-mode-alist`.
The following will do:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.php\\'" . php-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("/\\(templates\\|views\\)/.*\\.php\\'" . html-mode))
```

Comment: Just wanted to note that I use php-mode with flymake. Your solution had the unintended consequence of giving me exactly what I wanted, which is the html-mode key bindings, but still getting syntax checking with flymake. So, thanks!